# Handling a streaming server

Tags: c, sockets, concurrency, streaming

I have a server that sends data as fast as it can produce it and sends the data over a socket.  The server uses a queue and has a producer thread and a consumer thread that sends the produced data out a socket to the client.

The problem is reading the data on the client side.  How do I design a client to handle the data without it being out of sync?
If I send an acknowledgement from the client to the server I lose the concurrency speed on the server side.  How can I write/design a client to handle the incoming data fast enough?
Do I need to implement a queue on the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a requirement that you must use something other than TCP, just let TCP do the job of flow control for you. Let the client consume the data as fast as it wants to, and the server will block after it sends more data than the client is prepared to consume and it fills up the TCP window.

TCP will never get out of sync in the sense that data on the socket will always be delivered in order. But the server may certainly have sent out more data than the client has consumed and so it may have moved on to sending the next batch of data while the client is still consuming the previous one. Is this what you mean by out of sync?

You don't want to make the client send an acknowledge before the server starts on the next task because that will cost an RTT (round trip time, i.e. the time for the last of one batch of data to arrive at the client and for the acknowledge to go back), which will slow down your protocol on a high-latency link.

If you don't want this RTT price, you are inevitably going to have to allow either:

- for the client to request more than one batch at a time. You can use a tagged protocol like IMAP for this: the client submits several jobs at once on one socket, each with its own tag. The server responds to each request, with the tags in the header of each response so the client knows which response goes with which request. When the client has seen "enough" responses, it submits more requests. The client gets to control how many requests can be ongoing at the same time. If the client allows only one at a time, this degenerates to the simple ACK case with the RTT cost.
- for the server to work a little ahead of the client, sending several responses to the client before the client has acknowledged the first one. After the pipe is filled to the maximum number of unacknowledged jobs that the server is willing to allow, it waits to acknowledged and sends one additional job response for each acknowledge it receives from the client. If the server allows only one outstanding job, this degenerates to the simple ACK case as above. If the server allows too many unacknowledged jobs at a time, this degenerates to just filling up TCP's buffers and counting on TCP flow control to block the server until the client is ready to accept more data.

Comment: Well the data I am sending is structured with a header.  It is up to me how to structure the data. The problem I am having is the parsing of the data as it comes gets out of sync with the server because it is moving too fast.

Comment: You haven't said whether or not you would use TCP. If you use TCP, why would it get out of sync? If you don't, why not?

Comment: I am using TCP. It gets out of sync because the server sends the next set of data before the client is done processing the previous set of data.  I could have the client send an acknowledgement in between but then I lose the benefits of the concurrent server. I am trying to make a streaming server and client like you would for audio/video.

Comment: It will not get out of sync. TCP preserves the sequence of data from one end to the other. But let me see if you and I are understanding a different meaning for "out of sync". I will add more to the answer.